# Set xlim, ylim on polar plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using plots in polar coordinates in matplotlib to make a set of schematics, which look like,
[image: schematic0]

There's more white space than I would like between the subplots. Being in polar coordinates, set_xlim doesn't work, and set_ylim sets the radius limit. Can I adjust the xlim and ylim? What's the best way to reduce the whitespace between my subplots?

---

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def schematic0():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3., 3.))
    a_theta = np.linspace(-8, 8, 17) * np.pi / 8.
    a = np.cos(0.5 * a_theta)
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0., bottom=0., right=1., top=1.,
                        wspace=0., hspace=0.)
    for j in range(1, 5):
        fig.add_subplot(2, 2, j, projection='polar')
        ax = fig.gca()
        ax.bar(a_theta, a, width=np.pi/8, color='w')
        ax.spines['polar'].set_visible(False)
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        ax.xaxis.grid(False)
        ax.yaxis.grid(False)
    plt.savefig('foo0.png')
    return fig
```

I can make this look more like what I want by screwing with overlapping axes,
[image: schematic2]

```
def schematic2():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3., 3.))
    a_theta = np.linspace(-8, 8, 17) * np.pi / 8.
    a = np.cos(0.5 * a_theta)
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=-0.1, bottom=-0.05, right=1., top=1.05,
                        wspace=-0.1, hspace=-0.1)
    for j in range(1, 5):
        fig.add_subplot(2, 2, j, projection='polar',
                        axis_bgcolor=(1., 1., 1., 0.))
        ax = fig.gca()
        ax.bar(a_theta, a, width=np.pi/8, color='w')
        ax.spines['polar'].set_visible(False)
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        ax.xaxis.grid(False)
        ax.yaxis.grid(False)
    plt.savefig('foo2.png')
    return fig
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the right track with adjusting the overlap between plots. If you turn the grids back on, you can see that the plots are already bumping against each other in schematic0 and overlapping in schematic2. I'm not sure there's a better way to get rid of the white space than just messing with the subplots_adjust command like:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=-0.3, bottom=-0.05, right=1., top=1.05,
                    wspace=-0.45, hspace=-0.15)
```

Comment: This works for this application. I'm wondering if there's a way to "pan" within the axes, though.